# NPM error while installing packages on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, npm-install

I've been trying to install dependencies for two projects and while installing `xml2json` and `ursa` packages got the similar errors:

For `xml2json`:

```
C:\Users\home\Projects\project1\node_modules\node-expat>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "pangyp" rebuild )
module.js:491
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\home\Projects\project1\node_modules\node-expat\pangyp'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
```

For `ursa`:

```
C:\Users\home\Projects\project2\node_modules\ursa>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "pangyp" rebuild )
module.js:491
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\home\Projects\project2\node_modules\ursa\pangyp'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:598:3
```

Versions:

```
node v8.4.0
npm 5.3.0
Windows 7 Ultimate 64
```

I've run `npm rebuild node-expat` bun no effect.

Comment: Have you tried node-gyp rebuild?

Comment: I've tried to install bcrypt and node-gyp gave me some issues. Definitely install node-gyp is painful in windows. I ended installing Linux. Check these: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629 https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/849